# Chapter 7, eloquent JavaScript: LifelikeWorld

Tags: javascript, class, oop, prototype, javascript-objects

I've been reading this book, and, with a lot of hardship and other resources, made it through here (it alone was too hard but it is still quiet useful, along with other resources).

This is the code I finding hard to understand:

```
function LifelikeWorld(map, legend) {
  World.call(this, map, legend);
}
LifelikeWorld.prototype = Object.create(World.prototype);

var actionTypes = Object.create(null);

LifelikeWorld.prototype.letAct = function(critter, vector) {
  var action = critter.act(new View(this, vector));
  var handled = action &&
    action.type in actionTypes &&
    actionTypes[action.type].call(this, critter,
                                  vector, action);
  if (!handled) {
    critter.energy -= 0.2;
    if (critter.energy <= 0)
      this.grid.set(vector, null);
  }
};
```

`var actionTypes = Object.create(null); //` actionTypes creas a null object rigth?

`var handled`, I cant get my head around that variable, I undertand the concepts, does it check if action, actiontype are true? and, actionTypes[action.type] => actionType wasn't a null object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.create(null)` creates an object with `null` as a prototype. It means that unlike object literal (`{}`) or `new Object()` it doesn't inherit properties from `Object.prototype`.

`handled` variable is `true` when `action` variable is truthy, `actionTypes` variable contains key `action.type` and `actionTypes[action.type].call(this, critter, vector, action)` returns truthy value.